# 'ts-loader' vs. 'awesome-typescript-loader'

Tags: typescript, webpack

What is the difference between both these loaders?

It appears to solve the same purpose. Is there any specific difference or scenario that we should use one instead of other?

Comment: There's some [reference material on this](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/94). Otherwise the projects are at the same level of popularity on GitHub, same order of magnitude issues etc. I've been using `ts-loader` for a while and don't have any issues with it.

Comment: README includes the info now for those curious [here](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#differences-between-ts-loader)

Comment: Also see the following discussion, which shows that **ts-loader may be faster** than awesome-typescript-loader: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/497